# Returning Count of Values of Column D if Column G has a blank Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to set-up a formula to track whether or not we have received information from specific groups of people.  I need to know how many outstanding items we have from a certain people.

I want to return the count of column `d` cells equal to n1 where column `g` is a blank value.  I know that `COUNTIF(D:D,N1)` will not work because it returns the count of column `d` cells equal to `n1` regardless of whether or not column `g` is blank.

I have also tried the formula, `=IF(ISBLANK(G:G),COUNTIF(D:D,N1),COUNTIF(D:D,N1))`, but it also returns the count regardless of whether or not column `g` is blank.

Can anyone help direct me to the correct formula or function I will need to use?

I am using Microsoft Excel 2013.

Answer (score 3):

To count multiple simultaneous conditions, use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(D:D, N1, G:G, "")
```