# i want to count grades subject wise

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
   student 1  punjabi       A                hindi         B
              ss            C
             science        A   
             Computer       A

  student 2  punjabi        C
             Hindi          A
             ss             C
             Science        A
             computer        B
```

There are 50 studnents in worksheet. i want to count No. of A grade, no. of B grade in each subject.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, it is not clear what you are asking, what you have tried, and where you are stuck.  It is likely to be closed in its current state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning Count of Values of Column D if Column G has a blank Value](http://superuser.com/questions/684880/returning-count-of-values-of-column-d-if-column-g-has-a-blank-value)

Answer (score 2):

You want a COUNTIFS formula here. Something like this would probably work quite well

For this example I've assumed your titles are in column A, your grades are in row 1, and that the data you want starts in cell B2 in sheet "RESULTS", whilst your grades are in sheet "GRADES", with student names in row A, subjects row B, grades row C.

```
                 A             B            C          D
Punjabi
SS
Science
Computer
```

in cell b2 the formula you want is:

```
=COUNTIFS('GRADES'!$B:$B,'RESULTS'!$a2,'GRADES'!$C:$C,'RESULTS'!B$1)
```

What this does is count where Grades = the grade matching the top column and where subject=the subject matching the leftmost row, then returns the count. The dollar signs lock the sources. The reason I've locked the "Results" differently to the "Grades" is so you can just autofill the empty boxes to save re-typing the formula. The first one locks the column so it will move down correctly without moving across, whilst the second locks the row so it will move across but not down.